# GridGroupHeaderItem.AggregatesValues without Eval

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In [telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/grouping/group-header-and-footer-templates), It's say that aggregates values are store in the `AggregatesValues`. They even use it in the [exemple](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/grouping/group-header-and-footer-templates#group-footer-template).

But I find it impossible to prove. As everying is true until proven wrong .. right?
Let me provide you a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. So you could point my mistake.

#### Aspx :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="True" ShowGroupPanel="True">
    <MasterTableView>
        <GroupByExpressions>
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                <SelectFields>                       
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="GrpGroupID1" FieldName="GroupID" />
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="SumCount" FieldName="Count" Aggregate="Sum" />
                </SelectFields>
                <GroupByFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="GrpGroupID" FieldName="GroupID" HeaderText="" />
                </GroupByFields>
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
        </GroupByExpressions>
        <GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>eval GrpGroupID1:</td>
                    <td><%# Eval("GrpGroupID1") %></td>
                    <td> ||| </td>
                    <td>Bind GrpGroupID1:</td>
                    <td><%# ((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["GrpGroupID1"] %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>eval SumCount:</td>
                    <td><%# Eval("SumCount") %></td>
                    <td> ||| </td>
                    <td>Bind SumCount:</td>
                    <td><%# ((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["SumCount"] %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" UniqueName="Name_ID" />
            <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="GroupID" HeaderText="GroupID" SortExpression="GroupID" UniqueName="Name_GroupID" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name_Name" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" SortExpression="Text" UniqueName="Name_Text" />                
            <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count" SortExpression="Count" UniqueName="Name_Count" Aggregate="Sum" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

#### Code behind :

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    List<TmpType> myData = new List<TmpType>();

    List<string> firstNames = new List<string>() { "Angela", "Pamela", "Sandra", "Rita", "Monica", "Erica", "Tina", "Mary", "Jessica", "Loubega" };
    List<string> Location = new List<string>() { "Reunion", "Paris", "Bretagne", "Madagascar", "UK", "Maurice" };
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 88; i++)
    {
        TmpType row = new TmpType();
        row.ID = i + 1;
        row.GroupID = random.Next(10);
        row.Count = random.Next(10);
        row.Name = firstNames[random.Next(firstNames.Count)];
        row.Text = Location[random.Next(Location.Count)];
        myData.Add(row);
    }
    RadGrid1.DataSource = myData;
}

class TmpType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

#### Result :

Key and values of AggregatesValues in debug:

[image: Key and values of AggregatesValues in debug]

Exemple of data display:
[image: Exemple of data display]

As you can see in this exemple:
 - `Eval("SumCount")`  can find the value
when :
 - `((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["SumCount"]` fail !

The documentation says:

> the field alias name when you want to access the total aggregate of the items in the current group.

And `SumCount` is my FieldAlias.

#### What I try:

Here is a list of every thing i have try and the result.

**Eval() :** always almost correct, the approximate knowledge of nearly everything.

1. `Eval("GrpGroupID1")`, *Give the current value of the groupby field*, OK!
2. `Eval("SumCount")`, *Give the correct result of the aggregate function*, OK!
3. `Eval("Count")`, *Give the value of the row for this group (4)*, not Expected.
4. `Eval("Name_Count")`, *Error because this is not a properties of anything*, OK!

**AggregatesValues:** It will be fast !

1. `((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["GrpGroupID1"]`, *Give the current value of the groupby field*, OK!
2. `Everything else`, *Return NULL*

Those test have been made using a `asp:Label` and not using an Label.

#### Side note:

- Yes, I could simply use the `Eval`. But why? Why would I use an `Eval` when [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_3) state that I should not use it and when the Telerik documentation state that I can use the aggregates values collection.

#### Where is the question?

Many will be asking: "Where is the question?".
How can I get this `GridGroupHeaderItem.AggregatesValues` without `Eval` or `Bind` ?

Comment: What if you add `<%# Eval("SumCount") %>` into some label as `Text`?

Comment: In my code i have `<td><%# Eval("SumCount") %></td>`. I can put it in a Label Text but I don't see the point. The result will be the Same They will both give the good result.

Comment: OK, are you try use FieldName instead FieldAlias? `((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["Count"]`?

Comment: this one is null i have try every combination of column name, column field, GridGroupByField FieldAlias, GridGroupByField Name and even in last ressort HeaderText. I will Update tomorrow with a table with all possibilities and the result with Eval and AggregatesValues.

Comment: Try your databinding expression as a property of a server control, as previously mentioned.  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="<%# Eval("SumCount") %>" />  This is how it's done in the demo.

Comment: AS you would have expected using ASp:Label didn't change the behavior of a databinding. Eval and The AggregatesValues re mains the same. I have update the question with a list of things i have try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Name_GroupID" is missing the `Aggregate` property which would actually fill the Aggregate values collection. While Eval() has had access to the bound values, the Aggregate collection was still empty resulting in null values.

Try adding the `Aggregate="Sum"` to the column.

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="GroupID" HeaderText="GroupID" SortExpression="GroupID" UniqueName="Name_GroupID" Aggregate="Sum" />
```

**Result :**

Key and values of AggregatesValues in debug:

[image]
[image]

Example of data display:

[image]

**BIG thumbs** up for all the details you have put together! It was super nice to investigate this case!